# Lit not rendering slotted children

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit

I'd like to create a custom element to render a select input.

One parent creates `<select>` then a `slot` generates the `<option>` based on an array of choices.

```js
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit';

export class SimpleSelect extends LitElement {
  static properties = {};

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return html`<select><slot><option>None</option></slot></select>`;
  }
}
customElements.define('simple-select', SimpleSelect);

export class SimpleOptions extends LitElement {
  static properties = {
    options: {type: Array},
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.options = [];
  }

  render() {
    let opts = this.options.map((el) =>
      `<option value="${el.value}">${el.label}</option>`
    );
    return html`${opts.join("")}`;
  }
}
customElements.define('simple-options', SimpleOptions);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script type="module" src="./simple-greeting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <simple-select>
    <simple-options options='[{"label":"A","value":"a"},{"label":"B","value":"b"},{"label":"C","value":"c"}]'></simple-options>
  </simple-select>
</body>
```

This fails to render the slotted children; [playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=W3sibmFtZSI6InNpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZy5qcyIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiJpbXBvcnQge2h0bWwsIGNzcywgTGl0RWxlbWVudH0gZnJvbSAnbGl0JztcblxuZXhwb3J0IGNsYXNzIFNpbXBsZVNlbGVjdCBleHRlbmRzIExpdEVsZW1lbnQge1xuICBzdGF0aWMgcHJvcGVydGllcyA9IHt9O1xuXG4gIGNvbnN0cnVjdG9yKCkge1xuICAgIHN1cGVyKCk7XG4gIH1cblxuICByZW5kZXIoKSB7XG4gICAgcmV0dXJuIGh0bWxgPHNlbGVjdD48c2xvdD48b3B0aW9uPk5vbmU8L29wdGlvbj48L3Nsb3Q-PC9zZWxlY3Q-YDtcbiAgfVxufVxuY3VzdG9tRWxlbWVudHMuZGVmaW5lKCdzaW1wbGUtc2VsZWN0JywgU2ltcGxlU2VsZWN0KTtcblxuZXhwb3J0IGNsYXNzIFNpbXBsZU9wdGlvbnMgZXh0ZW5kcyBMaXRFbGVtZW50IHtcbiAgc3RhdGljIHByb3BlcnRpZXMgPSB7XG4gICAgb3B0aW9uczoge3R5cGU6IEFycmF5fSxcbiAgfTtcblxuICBjb25zdHJ1Y3RvcigpIHtcbiAgICBzdXBlcigpO1xuICAgIHRoaXMub3B0aW9ucyA9IFtdO1xuICB9XG5cbiAgcmVuZGVyKCkge1xuICAgIGxldCBvcHRzID0gdGhpcy5vcHRpb25zLm1hcCgoZWwpID0-XG4gICAgICBgPG9wdGlvbiB2YWx1ZT1cIiR7ZWwudmFsdWV9XCI-JHtlbC5sYWJlbH08L29wdGlvbj5gXG4gICAgKTtcbiAgICByZXR1cm4gaHRtbGAke29wdHMuam9pbihcIlwiKX1gO1xuICB9XG59XG5jdXN0b21FbGVtZW50cy5kZWZpbmUoJ3NpbXBsZS1vcHRpb25zJywgU2ltcGxlT3B0aW9ucyk7XG4ifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJpbmRleC5odG1sIiwiY29udGVudCI6IjwhRE9DVFlQRSBodG1sPlxuPGhlYWQ-XG4gIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT1cIm1vZHVsZVwiIHNyYz1cIi4vc2ltcGxlLWdyZWV0aW5nLmpzXCI-PC9zY3JpcHQ-XG48L2hlYWQ-XG48Ym9keT5cbiAgPHNpbXBsZS1zZWxlY3Q-XG4gICAgPHNpbXBsZS1vcHRpb25zIG9wdGlvbnM9J1t7XCJsYWJlbFwiOlwiQVwiLFwidmFsdWVcIjpcImFcIn0se1wibGFiZWxcIjpcIkJcIixcInZhbHVlXCI6XCJiXCJ9LHtcImxhYmVsXCI6XCJDXCIsXCJ2YWx1ZVwiOlwiY1wifV0nPjwvc2ltcGxlLW9wdGlvbnM-XG4gIDwvc2ltcGxlLXNlbGVjdD5cbjwvYm9keT5cbiJ9LHsibmFtZSI6InBhY2thZ2UuanNvbiIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiJ7XG4gIFwiZGVwZW5kZW5jaWVzXCI6IHtcbiAgICBcImxpdFwiOiBcIl4yLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwiQGxpdC9yZWFjdGl2ZS1lbGVtZW50XCI6IFwiXjEuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJsaXQtZWxlbWVudFwiOiBcIl4zLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwibGl0LWh0bWxcIjogXCJeMi4wLjBcIlxuICB9XG59IiwiaGlkZGVuIjp0cnVlfV0).

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't just combine the two components into one lit element component? Then you could pass in the options once and render the select/options appropriately

Comment: That would work too but this element is exposed to another API in another language where what is proposed here is more idiomatic.

Comment: It is an HTML restriction. ``<option>`` can only be used as a **direct child** of ``<select>``

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is how Lit Element is designed to be used. Looking at the lit playground code you can see that the browser doesn't render the component as options within a select object, it renders the two custom components:

[image: rendered HTML]

Because LIT element uses [shadowDOMs](https://lit.dev/docs/components/shadow-dom/), the select component doesn't have visibility into the option component.

You could probably use a query selector to manually extract the options from the simple-select, however, at that point why not just combine the components? Here is an [example](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=W3sibmFtZSI6InNpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZy5qcyIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiJpbXBvcnQge2h0bWwsIGNzcywgTGl0RWxlbWVudH0gZnJvbSAnbGl0JztcblxuZXhwb3J0IGNsYXNzIFNpbXBsZVNlbGVjdCBleHRlbmRzIExpdEVsZW1lbnQge1xuICBzdGF0aWMgcHJvcGVydGllcyA9IHtcbiAgICAgIG9wdGlvbnM6IHt0eXBlOiBBcnJheX0sXG4gIH07XG5cbiAgY29uc3RydWN0b3IoKSB7XG4gICAgc3VwZXIoKTtcbiAgICB0aGlzLm9wdGlvbnMgPSBbXTtcbiAgfVxuXG4gIHJlbmRlcigpIHtcbiAgICBsZXQgb3B0cyA9IHRoaXMub3B0aW9ucy5tYXAoKGVsKSA9PlxuICAgICAgaHRtbGA8b3B0aW9uIHZhbHVlPVwiJHtlbC52YWx1ZX1cIj4ke2VsLmxhYmVsfTwvb3B0aW9uPmBcbiAgICApO1xuICAgIHJldHVybiBodG1sYDxzZWxlY3Q-JHtvcHRzfTwvc2VsZWN0PmA7XG4gIH1cbn1cbmN1c3RvbUVsZW1lbnRzLmRlZmluZSgnc2ltcGxlLXNlbGVjdCcsIFNpbXBsZVNlbGVjdCk7XG4ifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJpbmRleC5odG1sIiwiY29udGVudCI6IjwhRE9DVFlQRSBodG1sPlxuPGhlYWQ-XG4gIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT1cIm1vZHVsZVwiIHNyYz1cIi4vc2ltcGxlLWdyZWV0aW5nLmpzXCI-PC9zY3JpcHQ-XG48L2hlYWQ-XG48Ym9keT5cbiAgPHNpbXBsZS1zZWxlY3QgXG4gICAgb3B0aW9ucz0nW3tcImxhYmVsXCI6XCJBXCIsXCJ2YWx1ZVwiOlwiYVwifSx7XCJsYWJlbFwiOlwiQlwiLFwidmFsdWVcIjpcImJcIn0se1wibGFiZWxcIjpcIkNcIixcInZhbHVlXCI6XCJjXCJ9XSc-XG4gIDwvc2ltcGxlLXNlbGVjdD5cbjwvYm9keT5cbiJ9LHsibmFtZSI6InBhY2thZ2UuanNvbiIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiJ7XG4gIFwiZGVwZW5kZW5jaWVzXCI6IHtcbiAgICBcImxpdFwiOiBcIl4yLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwiQGxpdC9yZWFjdGl2ZS1lbGVtZW50XCI6IFwiXjEuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJsaXQtZWxlbWVudFwiOiBcIl4zLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwibGl0LWh0bWxcIjogXCJeMi4wLjBcIlxuICB9XG59IiwiaGlkZGVuIjp0cnVlfV0) of the combined component

Answer (score 0):

working through your playground, I've update [Updated Playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-e1xuICAgICAgbGV0IG5ld09wdGlvbiA9IGRvY3VtZW50LmNyZWF0ZUVsZW1lbnQoJ29wdGlvbicpO1xuICAgICAgbmV3T3B0aW9uLnZhbHVlID0gZWwudmFsdWU7XG4gICAgICBuZXdPcHRpb24uaW5uZXJUZXh0ID0gZWwubGFiZWw7XG4gICAgICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZyggdGhpcy5wYXJlbnRFbGVtZW50LnF1ZXJ5U2VsZWN0b3IoJ3NlbGVjdCcpICk7XG4gICAgICB0aGlzLnBhcmVudEVsZW1lbnQucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcignc2VsZWN0JykuYXBwZW5kQ2hpbGQoIG5ld09wdGlvbiApO1xuICAgIH0pO1xuICAgIGNvbnNvbGUubG9nKCBwYXJlbnQgKTtcbiAgfSAgXG59XG5jdXN0b21FbGVtZW50cy5kZWZpbmUoJ3NpbXBsZS1vcHRpb25zJywgU2ltcGxlT3B0aW9ucyk7XG4ifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJpbmRleC5odG1sIiwiY29udGVudCI6IjwhRE9DVFlQRSBodG1sPlxuPGhlYWQ-XG4gIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT1cIm1vZHVsZVwiIHNyYz1cIi4vc2ltcGxlLWdyZWV0aW5nLmpzXCI-PC9zY3JpcHQ-XG48L2hlYWQ-XG48Ym9keT5cbiAgPHNpbXBsZS1zZWxlY3Q-XG4gICAgPHNpbXBsZS1vcHRpb25zIG9wdGlvbnM9J1t7XCJsYWJlbFwiOlwiQVwiLFwidmFsdWVcIjpcImFcIn0se1wibGFiZWxcIjpcIkJcIixcInZhbHVlXCI6XCJiXCJ9LHtcImxhYmVsXCI6XCJDXCIsXCJ2YWx1ZVwiOlwiY1wifSx7XCJsYWJlbFwiOlwiRFwiLFwidmFsdWVcIjpcImRcIn1dJz48L3NpbXBsZS1vcHRpb25zPlxuICA8L3NpbXBsZS1zZWxlY3Q-XG48L2JvZHk-XG4ifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJwYWNrYWdlLmpzb24iLCJjb250ZW50Ijoie1xuICBcImRlcGVuZGVuY2llc1wiOiB7XG4gICAgXCJsaXRcIjogXCJeMi4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcIkBsaXQvcmVhY3RpdmUtZWxlbWVudFwiOiBcIl4xLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwibGl0LWVsZW1lbnRcIjogXCJeMy4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcImxpdC1odG1sXCI6IFwiXjIuMC4wXCJcbiAgfVxufSIsImhpZGRlbiI6dHJ1ZX1d)

I think you are being limited by Lit, which seems to always want to create shadowDOM. The shadow DOM is difficult to traverse, it seems.

I say use Lit where necessary but, just try the basic web components approach.

I changed the "simple-select" element to extend just HTMLElement ( web-components, without Lit ) and used the connectedCallback function to create the default select element. I then was able to traverse and appendChild() from the simple-options element.

I'm sure there are some shortcuts left. In the playground, this is working: you can adjust the list of options inside the element options attribute

This doesn't work here but, this is the playground code.

```js
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit';
// don't use LitElement, just HTMLElement
export class SimpleSelect extends HTMLElement {
  static properties = {};

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    let selectElm = document.createElement('select');
    let optionElm = document.createElement('option');
    optionElm.value = "None";
    optionElm.label = "None";
    selectElm.appendChild(optionElm);
    this.appendChild( selectElm );
  }
}
customElements.define('simple-select', SimpleSelect);

export class SimpleOptions extends LitElement {
  static properties = {
    options: {type: Array},
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.options = [];
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    this.options.forEach((el) =>{
      let newOption = document.createElement('option');
      newOption.value = el.value;
      newOption.innerText = el.label;
      console.log( this.parentElement.querySelector('select') );
      this.parentElement.querySelector('select').appendChild( newOption );
    });
    console.log( parent );
  }  
}
customElements.define('simple-options', SimpleOptions);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lit/dist@3/core/lit-core.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 
</head>
<body>
  <simple-select>
    <simple-options options='[{"label":"A","value":"a"},{"label":"B","value":"b"},{"label":"C","value":"c"},{"label":"D","value":"d"}]'></simple-options>
  </simple-select>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

As said in the comments. It is a HTML limitation; `<option>` must be a **direct** child of `<select>`

To output:
[image]

From:

```html
<simple-select>
  v1:FOO;
  v2:BAR; 
  v3:BAZ;
</simple-select>
```

The native Web Component code is:

```html
<simple-select>
  v1:FOO ; v2:BAR
  ; 

    v3 : BAZ
</simple-select>

<script>
  customElements.define('simple-select', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // wait for parsed inner HTML
        this.innerHTML = "<select>" +
          this.innerHTML
            .split(";") // split to lines
            .filter(Boolean) // ignore empty lines
            .map(line => 
                 line.trim().split(":")) // trim whitespace, split to [value,label]
            .map(([value, label]) => 
                  `<option value="${value.trim()}">${label.trim()}</option>`)
            .join("") +
          "</select>";
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```